# onclick not working properly?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form where on every click, change, keyup, keydown.... it runs a function "isComplete()" to check that the values of each element and if all are filled out, good, else no.

The area I'm stuck is for this piece of code:

```
                                    <td class="edit-settings-content-table-left">Gender</td>
                                    <td class="edit-settings-content-table-right">
                                        <div style="display:inline;">
                                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                                <input type="radio" name="genderRadios" id="genderRadios" value="male" onclick="isComplete()"
                                                {@eq key=gender value="male"}
                                                    checked
                                                {/eq}
                                                > Male
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        <div style="display:inline;">
                                            <label class="radio-inline">
                                                <input type="radio" name="genderRadios" id="genderRadios" value="female" onclick="isComplete()"
                                                {@eq key=gender value="female"}
                                                    checked
                                                {/eq}
                                                > Female
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
```

if I click the male radio, it works, but clicking the female radio does not... any idea why?

Comment: Well for one both of your radio buttons have the same Id's. That maybe the issue. Without seeing the code though I can't tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Because id="genderRadios" is twice so you need to change id for female or male then it will work**

**HTMl**

```
<input type="radio" name="genderRadios" id="genderFemaleRadios" value="female" onclick="isComplete()"
                                                {@eq key=gender value="female"}
```

Comment: makes sense - i was using the id's to populate the backend after submit - anyways, just added a class to each and did a if or check and that works.